# Fortify Analysis Cross-Site Scripting: DOM sends unvalidated data to a web browser

Tags: security, xss, fortify, cross-site

```
redirectUrl = '/amazon/change/signin?flowtype',
window.location.href = redirectUrl;
```

Description: This method sends unvalidated data to a web browser on line 64, which can result in the browser executing malicious code.

fortify throwing below error in security.logs
Priority: Critical
Category: Cross-Site Scripting: DOM